# Counting Operations in the context of an Urn Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, polya-urn-model

I was tasked with the following question, regarding the counting of operations in the pseudo code provided that has nested for loops:

> Let *U* ={B1,B2,...,Bn} with n >= 3. Interpret the following algorithms in the context of urn problems. How many lines does it print?
>
> for i (member of) {1,2,...*n*} do
>
> > for j (member of) {*i*+1,*i*+2,...*n*}
> >
> > > for k (member of) {*j*+1, *j*+2,...*n*}
> > >
> > > print Bi, Bj, Bk

I Think this would print out 27 lines, 3*3*3, but it asks for it in the context of an urn problem. In that case, I guess it implies there is no replacement, so would it instead be something like 3 factorial?

Also, the Capital B has no value, it's just my shorthand for the subscripts.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Combinatorially**

The program prints three numbers in each line, so if we consider an urn containing $n$ enumerated bools form $1$ to $n$ the program consists of printing the corresponding numbers to every possible triple bools $B_i,B_j,B_k$ ($i< j< k$) this means that the number of printed lines is the number of different three bools in the urn so this is equal to the number of choosing $3$ bools in the urn.  hence the number of lines is:
$${n \choose 3}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} $$

**Formally (calulus)**

for every every $i$ we choose a $j$ between $i+1$ and $n$ and we the last loop prints $n-j$ lines, so the number of printed lines is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n n-j=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j'=1}^{n-i-1}j'=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(n-i-1)(n-i)}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i(i-1)}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$$

Comment: You say it prints "Bools..." does this mean it prints booleans? Also, in your combinatorially method, is that notation for something like Permutation/Combination? Additionally in this section, if n is 3, and you plug that in to the formula you use, does that mean it prints only one line? Because that doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: In the case $n=3$ there is only one line you can verify that yourself it's $B_1,B_2,B_3$

Comment: Not entirely. Does it have something to do with 3 being the maximum value in the i set?

Comment: **Execution of the program** first $i=1$ so$j\in\{i+1, \cdots,3\}=\{2,3\}$ now when $j=2$ then $k\in\{j+1,\cdots,3\}=\{3\}$ hence $k=3$ so we will print the first line $B_1,B_2,B_3$ because there is no other value of $k$ we will go to $j$ so $j=3$ is the next value for $j$ but in this case $k$ must be greater then $j+1=4$ so it's impossible nothing to print, now we have to change $i$ the next value is $i=2$ and $j$ must be greater then $i$ hence $j=3$ but no value is possible for $k\geq j+1=4$ and the same things happens for $i=3$ because $j$ must be greter then $i+1=4$ which is impossible.

Comment: I think I get it now. So no element of any of the sets in the nested loops can exceed the value of n, right?

Comment: yes this is  the constraint

Comment: Alright, thanks! I appreciate it